# Return a boolean value whether or not a process is running in AppleScript through System Events

Tags: applescript

I'm pretty good with AppleScript in general, so I feel that this shouldn't be difficult for me to figure out with just a little nudge in the right direction. I have looked around the site and found some other methods for this that don't use AppleScript, but as AppleScript is mainly what I know, I would prefer to use it for this purpose.

So, anyway, what I would like to do is to see if a process is already running (activated) before it proceeds to do the things I want to do. This should help clarify what I am trying to do:

```
tell application "AppleWorks 6" to activate
tell application "System Events"
repeat until "AppleWorks 6" is in the processes
        delay 3
        end repeat
end tell
--do script stuff with AppleWorks
```

When I tried this it returned false, even though AppleWorks was running:

```
"AppleWorks 6" is in the processes
```

Any basic help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a version of OS X later than Leopard, there is a `running` property you can leverage, so System Events aren't really needed.

```
tell application "AppleWorks 6" to activate
repeat
    delay 0.2
    if (running of application "AppleWorks 6") then exit repeat 
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks McUsr, I forgot that there was that option and, as I am using Snow Leopard, I know that should work just fine. Do you think it would run faster than the other solution from regulus6633 ?

Comment: I don't know if it is faster, the reason for doing like this, is to restrict the use of resources really, but, then again, I haven't looked at the events, but at least it doesn't address an app per say, so that part should be faster, when we are looking, I poll for running every 0.2 secs, so mine is using more resources, while it runs. If I recall correctly, neither way will really tell you if the app, just activated is ready to accept scripting commands. But then again, it is a good start. I think both ways really will suit you fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the "name" property of each process. Try this...

```
tell application "AppleWorks 6" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until "AppleWorks 6" is in name of processes
        delay 3
    end repeat
end tell
--do script stuff with AppleWorks
```